# Show data from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, express, mongojs

I have a problem fetching data from multiple collections inside a mongodb database. I am using mongojs to include them inside an html file using expressjs.

The Output is an error, that tasks_middle is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code-snippet:

```html
app.get('/', function(req, res){
        db.tasks_high.find(function (err, docs) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Tasks High Priority:',
            tasks_high: docs
        });
    })

        db.tasks_middle.find(function (err, docs) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Tasks Middle Priority:',
            tasks_middle: docs
        });
    })
});
```

Inside the viewer (index.ejs) I tried this:

```html
        <h1><%= title %> Prio High</h1>
        <ul>

            <% tasks_high.forEach(function(tasks_high){ %>
            <li><%= tasks_high.task %> <%= tasks_high.prio %> - <a class="deleteUser" data-id="<%= tasks_high._id %>" href="#">x</a></li>
        <% }) %>

        </ul>
        <br><br>

        <h1><%= title %> Prio Middle</h1>
        <ul>

            <% tasks_middle.forEach(function(tasks_middle){ %>
            <li><%= tasks_middle.task %> <%= tasks_middle.prio %> - <a class="deleteUser" data-id="<%= tasks_middle._id %>" href="#">x</a></li>
        <% }) %>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Well you really should not be doing that because if you want all the data at once then it really "should" be in the same collection. Is there some reason you are using `mongojs` as opposed to the standard node driver? Many years ago there might have been reasons to prefer the API, but not so much now. Most other driver implementations generally fall inferior of the base driver these days, and also suffer from a lack of maintenance. You'd likely do far better to switch.

Comment: Are you trying to query like you do in mongodb, db.tasks_middle ? or you have a custom module `db` defined ? 

Also there are mistakes like you are doing res.render two time in the same callback.

Comment: @FarhanTahir `mongojs`. That's how it presents things. The OP's question is not "how to make it work" but "how to get both result sets". So if they can be steered in a different direction it can actually make things easy for them. Not a syntax correction problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn I see now Thanks.

Comment: I try another approach. I thought it's easier to seperate entries in different collections, but it might be easier to just seperate them by some kind of flag.

Comment: I think I am not getting the correct usage of re.render(). Is it not possible to compile an index file with two seperated filtered results from a mongodb database? I want to separate tasks from high prio and mid prio. As you can see I use apt-get to fetch both of the data. I corrected some issues and I am able to see correct results when I route them to different pages (app.get('/tasks-high/') and app.get('/tasks-middle/'). But how can I compile this data on one index page?